# AspNet Identity with Identity Server Duplicate Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I spun up an identity server which uses AspNet Identity for the user store. The relevant tables were named Users, UserLogins, UserRoles, UserClaims, Roles, RoleClaims, and UserTokens. Then, I created a separate application for User management, which will enable administrative staff to create Users, change their passwords, and set their roles. I did this using AspNet Identity's UserManager and RoleManager classes. I provided the ApplicationIdentityDbContext, which was configured to use the same database as the Identity server, and naively assumed that the DbContext would figure out which tables to use. I added some custom properties to my ApplicationUser class, and ran the migrations... and here's what happened:

A bunch of new tables were generated on the database: AspNetUsers, AspNetUserRoles, etc...
And my UserManager in the admin application is putting data into *those* tables, instead of the ones that the Identity Server actually uses when authenticating users!

How do I go about this? I want to have one set of User store tables that are shared by the Identity Server and the UserManager application.

Thank you in advance for your repsonses.

Comment: You must have `ToTable("UserRoles");` etc. in one of your `OnModelCreating()`